# When asking, don't show already selected tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

It's a minor issue, but I think it's good to be reported.

When a user asks a new question he has to select tags for his question. For example, he selects [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.

If he write again [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) in the tags input, he will can select the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag again and again.

The good part is that the question doesn't show duplicate tags.

See the screen shot bellow:

> [image]

Comment: How has nobody thought of this already?!

Comment: I'd be in favor of something to not show an already entered tag in the tag suggestions box that pops up as you type (for convenience of having an extra space available for a *different* matching tag), but if some user sits there and types the same tag over and over manually, that's their problem. The system will catch it at submission, so I don't see why the client-side code should even care.